# php/mysql: 30 day interval for pre-paid membership

Tags: php, mysql, formula

I have a membership where each user gets 100 credits per 30 days interval. All memberships are prepaid for one to unlimited months upfront.

I want to reset the credits balance each 30 days back to 100 no matter if the user used his credits or not. I do not want to use any cronjob or something similar. I want to simply check when the user logs into the website if he already logged in the current 30 days interval and if not reset his credits balance.

I have in my DB a timestamp for the membership expiry date and when he logged in the last time.

Can anybody give me the formula how to calculate this?

I have so far:

```
$days = ($paid_until - $today) / 60 / 60 / 24;
$months = $days / 30;

echo "<pre>
Expires/ Renews in Days: $days
Expires/ Renews in Months: $months
```

Comment: A cron is in fact ideal for this. I would run the cron every day, and have a `started_at` date for each user, so that users who start halfway through a month do not get a half-month at the start and end of their membership. You can then calculate this on a per-user basis.

Comment: Do you want to assign an extra 100 credits per user, or just to set their credits to 100 regardless of the number of credits in their account? If the latter, what happens if they have more than 100 credits - are you OK with them losing credits?

Comment: This Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/11195130/ may be of help. It's based on 3 months, but you shouldn't have any trouble modifying that.

Comment: @halfer: your assumption is 100% correct. Balances need to be resetted to 100 no matter what. I dont want to use a cron however.

Comment: @Fred-ii- checking it now

Comment: You could make a test when a user visits the page whether a reset is due, and then just execute an update for that user if appropriate. Make sure you log what action you carry out in another table, so users who dispute their account balance can be told what was in their account prior to the reset, and why the reset was carried out on the day it happened.

Comment: @halfer that is very good input with the logging table. I will do this. Also the description of the solution sounds like exactly what I am looking for. However I dont know the correct formula for it. I only have 2 timestamps so far: paid_until (expiry date) and last_login

Comment: you just save the timestamp of the last time the counter was set to zero and do an sql `UPDATE mytable SET credits=0, last_reset_timestamp=NOW() WHERE last_reset_timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 day)`

Comment: (yo would have to run it it at least once per day, that's why a daily cron job would be the most efficient, but on every user login should also be fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking along these lines. Pseudo-code, which you can easily convert to PHP (not tested):

```
start transaction
if (last_reset_date not null)
{
    days_since_reset = last_reset_date
}
else
{
    // Handle the case where no reset has yet been performed
    days_since_reset = now - sign_up_date
    update last_reset_date to sign_up_date
}

months = floor(days_since_reset / 30)
if (months >= 1)
{
    // Add in a reset for every missing month
    for(month = 1 to months)
    {
        update last_reset_date += 30
        store balance in log, month number reset
        reset user balance to 100
    }
}
end transaction
```

The idea here is to reset all the missing months, even if this is not run for a particular user for over a month -- hence the loop.

Comment: thats coming close. But what if the user is logging in every day? He will never get his credits balance reset with this code.

Comment: Yes, that's rather my point @domi771. I wonder if logging in should not affect it? It should just be from their sign up date, every 30 days, his/her account is reset back to 100.

Comment: no, logging in should not affect the credit reset cycle. I believe it should be counted from the expiry date backwards every 30 days... too complicated for me :)

Comment: @domi771: can you explain what accounting system you are really trying to build? You cannot build it if you cannot describe it accurately and with data examples. Let me guess, though: the user has a `sign_up` date, and every 30 days from that date, their account should be reset. When this happens, you can set/update a `reset_date`, which is the date of the last multiple of 30 days. This will let you detect whether a reset is due or not (if it is over 30 days old a new reset is due). How does that sound?

Comment: that is 100% correct only I need to count the 30 days interval from the expiry date ($paid_until).

Comment: No, you also need to have a `sign_up` date @domi771. You cannot otherwise tell whether the user is due a reset, since you don't know how long they have been a member.

Comment: you are correct. My mistake. How would a possible formula look with a signup date? I can easy add this to the db.

Comment: I've added a new algorithm @domi771. Untested, should give you enough ideas to go on, even if it isn't perfect. Good luck!