# list of users who logged in for last week, month and year

Tags: oracle

I had written a query where i can get a list of users who logged into the system based upon last 1 day, 7 days, 90 days, 180 days and year and it was written in `MYSQL`

but I need to write the same query for my `oracle` database but i am very limited in my oracle knowledge, can anyone please share the code as to how i can write that such query

Database Table name is `JOBDesc` and column name is `lastLogin`

Like this question
[MYSQL last login and number of logins in last 3 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195130/mysql-last-login-and-number-of-logins-in-last-3-months)

my database is too large and big

Comment: Your question is unclear. In oracle, there is a view DBA_USERS which contains a column LAST_LOGIN. There you can get the information regarding all database users. 
As you are talking about a table JOB_Desc, please provide all relevant columns of this table. 
Are the "users who logged into the system" database users or users in your applications user management?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check login history from your database user, prior to oracle 10g (which is 9i and below) you  had two options:

Setup an event trigger that logs the information whenever user logs in or logs out into your audit table and query the  table directly.

On the recent versions,   you can  try  the query below.

```
select * from dba_hist_active_sess_history;
```

You can join this table with `dba_hist_sqltext` , `dba_users`  to ge the additional information about the user and the sql_text used in that session.

Comment: i better use query,rather this this because the db is huge and we have to filter results based on the days, months are maybe less